# Mysql primary key id issues

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

Basically I'm doing a system where the user enters a Name,E-mail,password & User type and these inputs are to be saved into my local database.
I am trying to create a Primary Key ID that automatically generates and increments the ID, so for the first input 1, second 2, third 3, etc.

Instead I'm getting a bunch of letters and random numbers such as the following;
***d7a8675a-c7cf-406a-983f-370d5b96fa62***

Here's what I've written on the Visual Studio Database Designer

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [Id]       int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [UserName] NCHAR (50)    NULL,
    [Email]    NCHAR (50)    NULL,
    [Password] NCHAR (50)    NULL,
    [Role]     NCHAR (15)    NULL
);
```

Also I forgot to mention that when I am accessing my Register.aspx page where the user is able to fill in the fields to be inserted into the DB i am calling the following on Click of the Register Button, could it be causing a problem wih my SQL code?

```
String insertQuery = "insert into Users (Id,UserName,Email,Password,Role) values (@Id ,@Uname ,@email ,@password ,@role)";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", newGUID.ToString());
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname",TextBoxUN.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPass.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", DropDownListRole.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: How do you save data, show entire code

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that when I am accessing my Register.aspx page where the user is able to fill in the fields to be inserted into the DB i am calling the following on Click of the Register Button, could it be causing a problem wih my SQL code?

Comment: So you save GUID  `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", newGUID.ToString());`. Skip this line and allow to work `IDENTITY`

Comment: The title says MySQL, but is that really true?

Comment: I've skipped that line and now It's filling my ID as null

Comment: @BendanS  `String insertQuery = "insert into Users (UserName,Email,Password,Role) values (@Uname ,@email ,@password ,@role)";`

Comment: i have no idea what database you are using nor what's happening ( do you get any error message?) nor what you are trying to achive

Comment: @Lad2025 I've done as you said, and now it's filling ID as null..

Comment: @lad2025 yes 

String insertQuery = "insert into Users (UserName,Email,Password,Role) values (@Uname ,@email ,@password ,@role)";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
        
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname",TextBoxUN.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPass.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", DropDownListRole.SelectedItem.ToString());

Comment: Change also table to `[Id]       int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,`

Comment: @lad2025 Thank you so much! Works

Comment: @lad2025 Can i ask a further question please?

I am trying to restrict data in my database to  be unique, example system name 'CRM' Can only be inputted in the database once, for that I have done this code but it's not working...

 String checksystem = "Select count(*) from Systems where SystemName='" + TextBoxSN.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checksystem, conn);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        if (temp == 1)
        {
          Response.Write("System Already Exists!");
        }

Comment: @BendanS Add [`UNIQUE Constraint`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or UNIQUE Index on that column. **[See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bdc7d/1/0)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change table definition to:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [Id]       int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [UserName] NCHAR (50)    NULL,
    [Email]    NCHAR (50)    NULL,
    [Password] NCHAR (50)    NULL,
    [Role]     NCHAR (15)    NULL
);
```

and your code:

```
String insertQuery = "insert into Users (UserName,Email,Password,Role) values (@Uname ,@email ,@password ,@role)";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname",TextBoxUN.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPass.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", DropDownListRole.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

You need to skip saving `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", newGUID.ToString());` and allow `IDENTITY` to fill the values.

Comment: It's me again! I just realized that what's happening now is that if I had to create accounts simultaneously the Id would increment by 1 correctly so account 1,2,3,4, etc. however If I delete account 3, what happens is that the rest of the accounts remain with the previous IDs and thus the account to be created next would be 5 so it would be 1,2,4,5.... can I possibly get some advise to fixing this?

Comment: @BendanS I would strongly recommend that you leave the identity values as they are. It is how `identity` works, it won't reuse deleted id. Think about this: "if this ID column is used as a foreign key on another table, changing them will get complicated very quickly". Don't manage it itself. If you still want to do it search for `Filling gaps with IDENTITY column`

Comment: @BendanS Please read also [IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775%28v=sql.110%29.aspx): `The identity property on a column does not guarantee the following: Reuse of values`

Comment: I get what you're saying! True, so just by having 1,2 and then 5 doesn't really bother oneself?

Comment: @BendanS I don't know your application, but id is rather for internal use and foreign keys, from user perspective it should be  negligible

Comment: also lad, I'm new to stack overflow but is there a function where I can message you privately? As I have an assignment which is close to being finished but I'm stuck at one point and it's not letting me move on and I need some help

Comment: @BendanS SO works in  question-answer manner. There is [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) for discussion. Don't get me wrong, I will help you but you shouldn't treat this as support/help-desk ;) If you have problem just ask new question, and I am sure you will get needed help.

Comment: @BendanS Also one question is solved you shouldn't edit it or add new cases. Ask new one instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary key definition is wrong
Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [Id]       int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    [UserName] NCHAR (50)    NULL,
    [Email]    NCHAR (50)    NULL,
    [Password] NCHAR (50)    NULL,
    [Role]     NCHAR (15)    NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Edit after your edit:

Why are you filling in a new GUID as the id parameter?

Its pretty clear why you're getting these random strings as your id...
If you define the id to automatically increment the number, you dont have to specify the id parameter

Comment: In addition Xeraphim, I've tried your edit but it just popps up an error saying "SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near 'AUTO_INCREMENT'.

Comment: I've removed the GUID as the id parameter and now the Id is being generated as NULL